# Inverter Fourier analysis

Tags: inverter, fourier, harmonics, equation

I have an inverter circuit like below:

[image]

I will use bipolar control method to produce sine wave. Our teacher said us prove basic harmonic of inverter is equal to multiplying of modulation index and Vd, so like:

\$ V_{01} = m_a \cdot V_d \$

I tried to modify sine basic harmonic but didn't work.

How can I prove this equation is right?

Comment: Beginning ... What is the definition of the basic first "harmonic" ? How can you get it mathematically? Apply the definitions.
What kind of control do you use ?
What kind of waveform do you get as output ?

Comment: @Antonio51 when you calculate fourier series of the output wave, the first sample of the fourier series is basic harmonic. I use bipolar pwm technic to prudce sine wave. The output will be sine wave.

Comment: Ok. I used a technique of "modulation" ... in time ... which makes it possible to obtain (with a filtering at a frequency higher than the "manufactured frequency" a "almost-sinusoidal" voltage including certain harmonics can be eliminated by a succession of pulses of calculated width and at a suitable position.

Comment: A succession of 6 pulses (3+, 3-) therefore theoretically make it possible to eliminate the harmonics (up to the eleventh, H11) by this control. That requires a resolution of a linear system in which the various points (position pulse, duration) are unknown. If we want to have a suppression of higher order harmonics, it will obviously require more and more pulses and therefore the system of equations becomes more and more complex.

Comment: So that the system produces a "sinusoid", in principle, it will take an "infinity". The filtering, which will obviously become easier and easier, will then be composed of elements (L, C) of "small" value and easy to perform or to integrate.
I don't know if this method is still used or if it has another name.

Comment: Nota: Commutations times are infinitively short.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/sinusoidal-pulse-width-modulation

Comment: My described method is    https://chppe.osu.edu/sites/chppe.osu.edu/files/uploads/Publications/A%20universal%20selective%20harmonics%20elimination%20method%20for%20high%20power%20Inverters.pdf         II paragraph

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks for your explanations but they are noy answer to my question.

Comment: In one paper, graphic shows that for a linear "output", MI index must be <=1. How is obtained this graphic ? The sinusoidal reference must be equal to the sawtooth used to generate the pulses. When reference is greater then sawtooth ... output is non-linear.

Comment: I think that with this information, it is possible to "draw" the equations of the "modulator" ("product" of two signals, comparator is also a "function"). Then calculating Fourier transform of such a "waveform", you will find that only the first harmonics is non-zero.

Comment: Try with two triangular pulses per cycle for beginning... Then raise the number of triangular waves.

Comment: this may help you         https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/34948978/chapter-8-comparators-13mb-analog-ic-designorg

Comment: I made a simulation of the circuit driving pulses as SPWM mode with SpectrumSoftware v12 (free) for having an idea of how to "calculate" simply FFT or equivalent harmonic contents. I have just a problem. I don't remenber how to calculate the Fourier transform of a "comparator". However, simulation show well your equation. But I don't know how send you the file for viewing the results. Sorry.

Comment: Yes. I can make another answer with the diagrams. I make it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework I'll only remind you that [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PWM) is achieved by comparing two voltages, resulting in an output whose amplitude is constant and duty cycle variable. One voltage is DC or variable (the reference voltage), while the voltage to be compared to is a ramp of some sort (the carrier), most often sawtooth or triangle. The width of the duty cycle is given by the *ratio* of the reference voltage and the carrier. So, for example, if the ramp is from \$0\$ to \$5\;\mathrm{V}\$, and the reference is \$2.5\;\mathrm{V}\$, then the duty cycle is \$2.5/5 = 0.5\$, or \$50\%\$ modulation. If the reference is \$0\mathrm{V}\$ then \$\alpha=0\;(0\%)\$, and if it's \$5\mathrm{V}\$ then \$\alpha=1\;(100\%)\$. For a bridge, the PWM's amplitude translates into the supply voltage, while an SPWM will have a variable reference voltage taking the shape of a sine. And if the sine has a frequency much lower than the carrier then for each period of the carrier the sine can be approximated to a DC voltage. The only thing left to do is to connect the dots.

---

To expand a bit on the approximation of the sine as a DC voltage, consider this as a mathematical case where the waveform is analyzed in terms of its derivative. That is, you take smaller and smaller steps such that the infinitesimal steps that you end up with, \$\mathrm{d}t\$, have such low variance that they can be considered continuous. This means that the carrier's frequency tends toward an infinite value.

Here, the reference is a sine with a frequency much lower than the carrier's, and the carrier's period is considered the \$\mathrm{d}t\$ term, so the analysis for one particular \$\mathrm{d}t\$ is done similar to the DC part: the average is \$\alpha\$ (times the difference between the highest and lowest supplies).

This was for one step, and the equivalent DC value of the \$\mathrm{d}t\$ represents the value of \$\alpha_0\sin(\mathrm{d}t_0)\$. The next step will consider the next \$\alpha_1\sin(\mathrm{d}t_1)\$, and so on. So if you cobble together all the averages you get the average of the PWM to be \$\alpha\sin(t)\$.

I've use \$\alpha\$ instead of \$m_a\$, and \$\sin(t)\$ instead of \$V_d\$, but the results are the same.

Comment: thank you for your explanation but I couldn't find. My brain will blow up. I don't see any relationship between modulation index and output voltage because modulation index is about triangular wave and control wave, none of them are not reflected to output. They are used to just generate pwm pulses.

Comment: @Piko Exactly, and those pulses have an average of ...?

Comment: @Piko I've updated my answer, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

As nothing is said about << how >> to "produce" the "waveforms" ...

From the reference given in above comments ...
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/sinusoidal-pulse-width-modulation

[image]

Here are some simulations done.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When needed, firstly I use an electronic simulator for debugging the problem. In these picture, You can measure the magnitude versus frequency in the low part of picture plotting the harmonic content of output calculated by microcap v12 from SpectrumSoftware (free).

The point of interrest is at 50 Hz, frequency used in EU countries. Only the case n=1 does not verify your equation.

Comment: in your situation, output voltage is related with modulation index because output is related with control and triangle wave but in my situation, we use modulation index for just generate pwm signals and pwm signals is related with output voltage just frequency not about amplitude. Because of that I am not able to find the relationship that I mentioned in my post.

Comment: See above ... answer from "concerned citizen" ... If n is very high ... PWM pulse "duration" and "mean" are proportional to the "Input voltage" modulator through MI index. The output voltage (peak Vd) contain "harmonics" at "very high" frequencies. These are discarded by filtering. So, output voltage is proportional through Vd and MI.